# What is the correct format for the expiration date in the citrix license server?

Tags: powershell, citrix

I am trying to configure a script in ps that gets me data from the citrix license server. I need it to output the license count, usage and the expiration date of the license. I cant seem to get it to work as i dont know the correct property of the expiration object name.

I currently have it set up like this:

```
$LicenseData |  select-object pld -unique | foreach { 
$CurrentLicenseInfo = "" | Select-Object License, Count, Usage, pctUsed, Alert, Expiry
$CurrentLicenseInfo.License = $_.pld    
$CurrentLicenseInfo.Count   = ($LicenseData  | where-object {$_.PLD -eq $CurrentLicenseInfo.License } | measure-object -property Count      -sum).sum 
$CurrentLicenseInfo.Usage   = ($LicenseData  | where-object {$_.PLD -eq $CurrentLicenseInfo.License } | measure-object -property InUseCount -sum).sum
$CurrentLicenseInfo.Expiry   = ($LicenseData  | where-object {$_.PLD -eq $CurrentLicenseInfo.License } | measure-object Expiry -sum).sum
$CurrentLicenseInfo.pctUsed = [Math]::Round($CurrentLicenseInfo.Usage / $CurrentLicenseInfo.Count * 100,2)
$CurrentLicenseInfo.Alert   = ($CurrentLicenseInfo.pctUsed -gt $UsageAlertThreshold)`
```

Im not sure if i have to use the Get-date format instead or have to have the property name. I cant find this info in the citrix license server documentation. The purpose of the script is to obtain the citrix license usage including the expiration which does show if i use the lmutil lmstat tool. Im a bit rusty so any advice was be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you can find it using `($LicenseData  | where-object {$_.PLD -eq $CurrentLicenseInfo.License }) | Format-List *` (or use `| Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty`)

Comment: This did not output the license expiration but did stop alot of the syntax errors coming up. Ill try to work with this format to get it working.